# LateInitializationError flutter

Tags: flutter, dart

why does this error occur
I've been trying to figure this out for two days
thank you to those who helped

LateInitializationError: Field '_ANADATA@583274105' has not been initialized.

```
var test =  databaseHelper();

test.ogrenciEkle(ogrenci("Ahmet", 1));



import 'dart:async';
import 'dart:io';
import 'package:sqflite/sqflite.dart';
import 'package:path_provider/path_provider.dart';
import 'package:path/path.dart';
import '../model/Ogrenci.dart';

class databaseHelper {
  static late databaseHelper _ANADATA;
  static late Database _DATABASE;
  String ogrenciTablosu = "ogrenci";
  String columID = "id";
  String columName = "ad_soyad";
  String columnActv = "aktif";

  factory databaseHelper() {
    if (_ANADATA == null) {
      _ANADATA = databaseHelper.init();
      return _ANADATA;
    } else {
      return _ANADATA;
    }
  }

  databaseHelper.init();

  Future<Database> getDatabase() async {
    if (_DATABASE == null) {
      _DATABASE = await _initializeDatabase();
      return _DATABASE;
    } else {
      return _DATABASE;
    }
  }

  _initializeDatabase() async {
    Directory dir = await getApplicationDocumentsDirectory();
    String dbPath = join(dir.path, "db.sql");
    var ogrenciDb =
        await openDatabase(dbPath, version: 1, onCreate: _createDatabase);
    return ogrenciDb;
  }

  Future<void> _createDatabase(Database db, int version) async {
    await db.execute(
        "CREATE TABLE $ogrenciTablosu ($columID INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT,$columName TEXT,$columnActv INTEGER) ");
  }

  Future<int> ogrenciEkle(ogrenci ogrenci) async {
    var db = await getDatabase();
    var sonuc = await db.insert(ogrenciTablosu, ogrenci.toMap());

    return sonuc;
  }
}
```

Comment: await this call`await test.ogrenciEkle(ogrenci("Ahmet", 1));`.

Comment: Future<void> initState() async {
    test = databaseHelper();
    await test.ogrenciEkle(ogrenci("Ahmet", 1));

  }
_myAppState.initState() returned a Future.

Comment: var test = databaseHelper();
  
LateInitializationError: Field '_ANADATA@21274105' has not been initialized.

Comment: Your `factory` constructor reads from `_ANADATA` to check if it's null, but it has not been initialized yet.  You will need to make `_ANADATA` nullable instead of being `late`.  Read https://dart.dev/null-safety/understanding-null-safety to understand null safety.

Comment: _ANADATA==null , is causing the problem... you can't do any operations (== is an operation) on a late variable if it's not initialized